# How to grep a column by avoiding title headings?

Tags: bash, awk, grep, cut

I have an output something like this

```
#################################################################
# If you used AutoDock Vina in your work, please cite:          #
#                                                               #
# O. Trott, A. J. Olson,                                        #
# AutoDock Vina: improving the speed and accuracy of docking    #
# with a new scoring function, efficient optimization and       #
# multithreading, Journal of Computational Chemistry 31 (2010)  #
# 455-461                                                       #
#                                                               #
# DOI 10.1002/jcc.21334                                         #
#                                                               #
# Please see http://vina.scripps.edu for more information.      #
#################################################################

Detected 4 CPUs
Reading input ... done.
Setting up the scoring function ... done.
Analyzing the binding site ... done.
Using random seed: -1786073016
Performing search ... done.
Refining results ... done.

mode |   affinity | dist from best mode
     | (kcal/mol) | rmsd l.b.| rmsd u.b.
-----+------------+----------+----------
   1        -10.7      0.000      0.000
   2        -10.4      0.460      1.612
   3         -8.6      1.625      6.452
   4         -8.1      1.515      5.404
   5         -8.1      1.569      5.214
   6         -7.9      1.616      6.148
   7         -7.9      1.380      2.324
Writing output ... done.
```

But I want only the following as output

```
-10.7
-10.4   
-8.6    
-8.1    
-8.1    
-7.9   
-7.9
```

I was trying in the line of the following commands

```
grep ' kcal/mol ' ./1/data01/lig2_noch.pdbqt.txt | awk '{print $2}' >>test1.txt
```

But no success, can anyone give me a quick fix on how to get only $2 numbers as mentioned above in these kind of files?

Comment: Why are you using `grep ' kcal/mol '`? That will print only the heading, not skip them.

Answer (score 3):

Test if the first column is a number, then print the second column.

```
awk '$1 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ {print $2}' ./1/data01/lig2_noch.pdbqt.txt >> test1.txt
```

Comment: I got an output like `If
#
O.
AutoDock
with
multithreading,
455-461
#
DOI
#
Please
|
(kcal/mol)
-8.4
-8.3
-8.0
-7.7
-7.6
-7.6
-7.6
-7.2
-7.2`

Comment: I got the same output by using grep '  ' ./1/data01/lig2_noch.pdbqt.txt | awk '{print $2}' >>test1.txt any idea how to only get the numbers not the previous things?

Comment: I changed `\d` to `[0-9]`, since `awk` doesn't understand that regular expresison. Now it works for me.

Comment: Very elegant solution!

Comment: @SoumendranathBhakat Before that fix I wasn't getting any output, I don't know why you were getting every line.

Comment: Seems working for me too. Very noob question if I change it to 1-10 it will give only -10.7 as output. Why you choose 0-9 ?

Comment: `[0-9]` matches any character in that range, and the `+` means to match any sequence of those characters. If you don't understand basic regular expression syntax, read the tutorial at regular-expression.info.

Answer (score 0):

try: If your output shown will be always same then following may help you in same.

```
awk '/output ... done/{A=""} /^-----/{A=1;next} A{print $2}'   Input_file
```

looking for a sting output ... done and making a variable A's value to NULL. Then again looking for a pattern where a line starts from ----- then making variable A's value to 1. Then mentioning A means checking if A's value is NOT null then print the $2(second field which is as per your requirement). Mentioning Input_file here.

Also either you could use above or if that output is coming from running a script then you could try with:

```
./your_already_running_script | awk '/output ... done/{A=""} /^-----/{A=1;next} A{print $2}'
```